# duplicate of entry in database of longitude and latitude using javascript php laravel

Tags: javascript, php, database, laravel, autocomplete

im stuck in here for 24 hours i've been trying to get different values.
i'm getting the address of each student as well as the longitude and latitude.

here is my view, i used javascript  :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropdown").change(function() {
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    $("#textboxDiv").html('');
     $("#schoolloc").html('');

    if(selVal > 0) {
        for(var i = 1; i<= selVal; i++) {
             $("#textboxDiv").append('<input type="hidden" 
    value="student'+i+'" name="stud[]" />');
             $("#schoolloc").append('<input type="text" 
    name="studlocation[]" id="studlocation'+i+'" />');
        var input = document.getElementById('studlocation'+i+'');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    $("#slat").html('');
    $("#slng").html('');
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
     var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var lng= place.geometry.location.lng();
     $("#slat").append('<input type="hidden" name="slat" value="'+lat+'" />');
    $("#slng").append('<input type="hidden" name="slng" value="'+lng + '" />');
       console.log(lat);
         });
                   }

               }
                });
              });
```

and here is my controller:

```
 $students = (array)$request->stud;
 $locations = (array)$request->studlocation;

 for ($i = 0; $i < count($students); $i++){

$hm = new HouseMate;

$hmid = rand();
$hm->hmid=$hmid;
$hm->rId_fk=$renterid;
$hm->person=$students[$i];  
$hm->location=$locations[$i];
$hm->$lat=$request->slat;
 $hm->lng=$request->slng;


$hm->save();
```

}

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how save array of lat and long from autocomplete ? if i have inputted two autocomplete the only things that it'll append is the last data iputted